# Putting iAd banner at the bottom of app

Tags: ios, cordova, iad

i just implemented a basic iad banner and on the xib file i dragged and dropped the bannerview on the bottom of the iphone and ctrl clicked file owner and dragged it to the adview. The issue is when I load it onto an iphone 5, the banner is only 3/4ths of the way down because the xib view is on iphone 4. Is there anyway i can avoid the xib view altogether and have some code that just puts the banner at the bottom no matter the device. This is my first time using iAds so i'm a bit new to it.

Thanks

In my viewController.m file here is a few lines of code, i'm assuming this is where the code would go if it's possible.

```
@synthesize adView;

- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
[adView setHidden:NO];
}

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
[adView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: A couple of comments: `1:` There is no need to use `@synthesize` anymore. `2:` If you are using properties, you should use the accessor methods (otherwise why bother) so use `self.adView` to be safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has some sample code that demonstrates the proper way to display banner-style iAds in your app. [Check it out here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010198). In particular, take a look at the ContainerBanner project.

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad:

```
adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
```

Also check out Robotic Cat's comment, as he is correct.